# Python web-crawling and regular expression

Tags: regex, python-3.x, web-crawler

I'm crawling the game players name with regular expression on "op.gg" web site.

I used reqexr.com website to check my regular expression of what I want to get and I found 200 players.

But my python codes doesn't work. I intended to insert 200 datas into list. but the list is empty.

I think a single quotation mark(') doesn't work on my python code.

here is my piece of codes..

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

user_name = input()

def hex_user_name(user_name):
    hex_user_name = [hex(x) for x in user_name.encode('utf-8')]
    for i,j in enumerate(hex_user_name):
        hex_user_name[i] = '%'+j[2:].upper()
    return ''.join(hex_user_name)

def get_user_name(user_name):
    q = re.compile('k\'>([^<]{1,16})', re.M)
    site = 'http://www.op.gg/summoner/userName=' + user_name
    source_code = requests.get(site)
    plain_text = source_code.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text, 'lxml')
    name = soup.find_all('a')
    listB = q.findall(re.sub('[\s\n,]*', '' ,str(name)))
    print(listB)

get_user_name(hex_user_name(user_name))
```

I strongly doubt that this line

```
q = re.compile('k\'>([^<]{1,16})', re.M)
```

has a problem.. but I couldn't find any mistake.

this is what I want to use on regular expression: `k\'>([^<]*)`

And 이곳은지옥인가(Korean word) is what I want to get the data on HTML code.

```
<div class="SummonerName">
      <a href="//www.op.gg/summoner/userName=%EC%9D%B4%EA%B3%B3%EC%9D%80%EC%A7%80%EC%98%A5%EC%9D%B8%EA%B0%80" class="Link" target='_blank'>이곳은지옥인가</a>
</div>
```

I really appreciate you guys helping me out..

Answer (score 0):

Your regex is working

```
>>> x = ('<a href="//www.op.gg/summoner/userName=%EC%9D%B4%EA%B3%B3%EC%9D'
         '%80%EC%A7%80%EC%98%A5%EC%9D%B8%EA%B0%80" class="Link" '
         'target=\'_blank\'>이곳은지옥인가</a>')
>>> import re
>>> q = re.compile('k\'>([^<]{1,16})', re.M)
>>> q.findall(x)
['이곳은지옥인가']
```

Probably enough `plain_text` to your regex

```
listB = q.findall(re.sub('[\s\n,]*', '' , plain_text))
```

because `soup.find_all('a')` [returns a `list`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs3/documentation.html#The%20basic%20find%20method:%20findAll(name,%20attrs,%20recursive,%20text,%20limit,%20**kwargs)), so you would need to loop through that.

Coercing the list into a `str` ca get messy, because it will escape the `'` and/or `"`

```
>>> li = ['k\'b"n', 'sdd']
>>> str(li)
'[\'k\\\'b"n\', \'sdd\']'
>>> 
>>> li
['k\'b"n', 'sdd']
>>> 
>>> 
>>> li = ["k'b\"n", 'sdd']
>>> li
['k\'b"n', 'sdd']
>>> str(li)
'[\'k\\\'b"n\', \'sdd\']'
>>>
```

That would easily break your regex.